# React - rerender relative time every few seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time

I'm creating a real time application with React.
I'm using Mobx as my state container. (doesn't matter, Redy

I have a component showing relative time, since the last order has arrived. ( `<FormattedRelative />` component taken from react-intl library -
showing something like "1 minute ago").
This "1 minute ago" message gets snapshotted when UI gets rendered for the first time. But as the time goes, this gets outdated and inaccurate.

What do you think is the best and idiomatic approach to keep those messages up to date (let's say old at most 10 seconds)?

Should I somehow schedule re-render with setInterval? Or should I periodically change some value in my store, so my UI gets re-rendered?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [react-timeago](https://github.com/nmn/react-timeago). it is highly customizable for international usage with support for Localization
Ex:- A custom formatter with french strings

```
import TimeAgo from 'react-timeago'
import frenchStrings from 'react-timeago/lib/language-strings/fr'
import buildFormatter from 'react-timeago/lib/formatters/buildFormatter'

const formatter = buildFormatter(frenchStrings)

// in your react component
<TimeAgo date='Feb 1, 1966' formatter={formatter} />
```